# Add property to mongoose document pre lowercase validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want a user object to maintain case sensitivity for display purposes, but be lowercased for unique-ness purposes. My first thought is to add a `usernameDisplay` property to the schema and try a pre-save hook:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    usernameDisplay: String,
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    this.usernameDisplay = this.username;
    next();
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The `username` and `usernameDisplay` properties are both saved as lowercase usernames.

I think the following would work: remove the `lowercase` validation in the schema and do this:

```
userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    this.userDisplayName = this.username;
    this.username = this.username.toLowerCase();
    next();
});
```

but now I'm curious about how Mongoose does the lowercase validation/alteration to the incoming data.

Please let me know if my question isn't clear and I can try to update it for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i dont think mongoose has a lowercase validation it seems rather specific to be included.

Secondly, your approach seems fine to me. However I recommend using mongoose virtuals (this is a textbook example of [virtuals application](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-virtual)).
Short reference: Virtuals are fields that are not stored but calculated each time. So you could do something like this

```
userSchema.virtual('userDisplayName').get(function(){
    return this.username.toLowerCase();
});
```

Using "userDisplayName" will be transparent but the field will not be stored.

Last but not least, regarding your code, it is saving the same data in the DB because of this line

```
this.userDisplayName = this.username;
```

You are assigning 2 names to the same reference, thus changing one changes the other. Instead try this.

```
this.userDisplayName = this.username.toLowerCase();
next();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: About the `this.userDisplayName = this.username` - I assumed that because username is a string, and strings are passed by value instead of reference, that changing one shouldn't change the other. Is that incorrect? Also, schemas do have a "lowercase" option to their fields. Maybe "validation" is the wrong word though, since it just lowercases any input automatically. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: Also, I'm wanting to save the username in the DB as an all-lowercased version of whatever the user submits. That way the `unique: true` validation kicks in no matter what the person typed in. But I still want to be able to display the username with the capitalization the user originally entered. Your example has it backwards I think.

Comment: Ok, sorry i got it wrong. I just checked the mongoose documentation and you are right, there is a lowercase option to force the field to lowercase. It seems to do exactly what you need. However, i would try making the `this.userDisplayName = this.username` modification, because if it is not that i dont see any other reason why its behaving that way.

Comment: I think I was more just curious about _when_ mongoose lowercases things, because my first try wasn't working. Maybe for some reason the strings aren't passed by value in that instance. Oh well, not a big deal. I'll stick with my second solution for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can apply lowercase in the mongoose model:

```
stuff: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/schematypes.html